# Differentiation with respect to a self-defined function in matlab

Tags: matlab, function, differential-equations

I have made a function in func.m which is defined as follows:

function f = func(b)
f = b^2+1;
end

now i wish to differentiate with respect to that function i.e.
find 2*b+1 with a given value for b (lets say 1)

I tried diff(func(1)) but it returned an empty matrix.

Any ideas?

thanks

Comment: Note that the derivative of a constant is always zero, so the derivative is just f'(b)=2*b.

Answer (score 0):

Your input argument `func(1)` is a vector of size 1x1. The function diff caled on vectors is this one: [here](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/diff.html). If you want to use the symbolic one, which allows to differentiate a function but requires the symbolic toolbox, you have to use a symbolic input. Explained [here](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/symbolic/diff.html)

Example:

```
% create a symbolic variable x
syms x
%differentiate f(x) and name it f1(x)
f1(x)=diff(f(x))
%get the value at point 1
f1(1)
```

If you don't have the symbolic toolbox, there is also a numeric solution.